# Handling response from HTTP POST without access to the request in Next.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, post, next.js

I'm implementing the payment gateway API of a local company that provides a HTML fragment that renders a button in my page to handle the checkout and payment in a modal-like interface that is out of my control (without redirecting the user outside of my page).

The fragment is a script tag like this:

```
<form action="http://localhost:3000/api/checkout" method="POST">
  <script
    src="https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/integrations/v1/web-tokenize-checkout.js"
    data-public-key="ENV_PUBLIC_KEY"
    data-transaction-amount="100.00">
  </script>
</form>
```

After the Card and payment info is entered by the user, the gateway makes a POST request to my API endpoint 'checkout' in Next.js (specified in the action attribute of the form) with some data to confirm the transaction as shown in the following.

/pages/api/checkout.js:

```
export default (req, res) => {
    mercadopago.configurations.setAccessToken(configAccess_token);
    var payment_data = {
         transaction_amount: 100,
         token: token,
         description: 'Blue shirt',
         installments: installments,
         payment_method_id: payment_method_id,
         issuer_id: issuer_id,
         payer: {
         email: 'john@yourdomain.com'
         }
     };
     // Save and process the payment:
     mercadopago.payment.save(payment_data).then((data) => {
         Console.log(data.status);
     }).catch( (error) => {
         console.error(error)
     });
  };
```

I receive the payment info and I'm able to process the payment, however, the page keeps waiting for a promise-like response (stays loading indefinitely) after making the POST request. How could I handle this promise/response if I'm not explicitly making the POST request? I don't have access to the code that makes the POST request as it comes from the payment gateway itself.

I tried returning a response from my API endpoint with some data like this...

```
res.statusCode = 200;
res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
res.json({success: 'success!'});
```

... but it just renders the JSON data as plain text after redirecting me to my API URL: "http://localhost:3000/api/checkout".

The API documentation doesn't offer any info about this matter as far as I know after hours researching it.

My goal is to display some kind of notification of success (like a toast for example) or find any other way of letting the user know the transaction was completed without creating a generic '/success' page that anyone could visit at any time.

I have little experience in backend development so any help to put me in the right direction to handle this promise/response would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Have you tried returning a JSON response like they mention in [their documentation](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/guides/online-payments/web-tokenize-checkout/receiving-payment-by-card) (response part on step 4)?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. That step refers to the actual payment in the node.js enviroment. Returning a JSON just redirect me to my API endpoint where I processed the payment and renders the JSON in plain text. I could create a '/success' page and point the user there afterward but my goal is to notify the user about the outcome of the process without using a generic page accessible at all times. Thanks in advance!